# Copy Data from JTable into ArrayList

Tags: jtable

Hi how can I copy data from my JTable into an ArrayList? 
I dont want the first row which is the columns name, I want everyother row. Thanks

Comment: How are you storing your data in the table .. is it Object wise or just a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the data in the table with out using any object then just traverse row by row on the table and get every object and store it in the List.

Example: This is when you are using a list to store the data.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>;

for(int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
    for(int column = 0; column = table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
      list.add(table.getValueAt(row, column));  
    }
}
```

Finally you will get all the objects in the list.

**EDIT:**

Since each row is an object of type `CustomObject` we need to set each value of the table to the object of type `CustomObject` and add it to the List for every row.

```
class CustomObject {
   Object one;
   Object two;
}

List<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<CustomObject>;

for(int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
  CustomObject object = new CustomObject();
    for(int column = 0; column = table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
       switch(column) {
            case 0:
                  object.setOne(table.getValueAt(row, column));
                  break;
             case 1: 
                  object.setTwo(table.getValueAt(row, column));
                  break;
       }
    }
    // Store each object in the list.
    list.add(object);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think this would work, however i would like to convert each row as a string. So once it gets the whole rows values I want the object converted to a string and that string stored into the arraylist, thanks

Comment: Thanks but instead of creating more than one Object, cant you jsut have an object like Object a and then convert that to a string e.g. .toString? As this is what I was thinking but did not know how to implement it. Thanks

Comment: Can I know what use will it make if you make an entire row as a single object and do object.toString()? AFAIK it will just print the object reference value and why to store it was my question?

Comment: Well, Im hoping to combine two arrayLists of String with the same type of data, so it will be easier for me.

Comment: Then I hope you should do something like, get list of object from both the table and store them in the list (as shown in the above code.) Then for each object check the data members are equal to the object's data members in other list.

Comment: Ahh ok, so does that mean I dont convert each row into a string?

Comment: See this I just printed object.toString() to the object of CustomObject class then I got this as com.CustomClass.CustomObject@85af80. Is this giving any information to you?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred, and robust, way is using the TableModel. Use JTable.getModel() to get it.
Once you have a TableModel, you can use its API to know what value it has at any location using getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) and then store it in you List.

Comment: yeah thats what I have been using, but I want each row to be stored as one in an arralist. they are all strings.